# Python dependency resolution

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have previously created a python package and uploaded it to pypi. The package depends upon 2 other packages defined within the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
from dominos.version import Version

def readme():
  with open('README.rst') as file:
    return file.read()

setup(name='dominos',
      version=Version('0.0.1').number,
      author='Tomas Basham',
      url='https://github.com/tomasbasham/dominos',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['dominos'],
      install_requires=[
        'ratelimit',
        'requests'
      ],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

As both of these were already installed within my virtualenv this package would run fine.

Now trying to consume this package within another python application (and within a separate virtualenv) I have defined the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
dominos==0.0.1
geocoder==1.13.0
```

For reference `dominos` is the package I uploaded to pypi. Now running `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` fails because dependencies of `dominos` are missing:

```
ImportError: No module named ratelimit
```

Surely `pip` should be resolving these dependencies since I have defined them in the `setup.py` file of `dominos`. Clarity on this would be great.

Comment: What happens if you create a clean virtualenv locally, copy in the dominos package and run `python setup.py install`? How did you deploy your code to PyPI? Can you `pip install dominos`?

Comment: I can do neither of these things. However if I first install the two dependencies manually `pip install ratelimit` and then `pip install dominos` everything is fine. I'm sire this is my fault somewhere but I cannot figure it out. I'll update my question to include the entire setup.py file for clarity

Comment: @tomasbasham does the `dominos` setup.py include `import ratelimite` or import something that would `import ratelimit`? Can you show the entire `setup.py`?

Comment: @jordanm just updated with full setup.py

Comment: I see the update, does `dominos.version` import `ratelimit`?

Comment: It does not include any other files or packages

Comment: The package's `__init__.py` does, that's causing your issue.

Comment: If you import the package in setup.py, then its dependencies must already be available before you've set it up...

Comment: Ah, ok. So `__init__.py` gets called during installation? I'm still a little new to Python and this __init__ file rally confuses me

Comment: It gets called because of your import of `dominos.version` in `setup.py`.

Comment: Right, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Comment: It does *when you explicitly import the package*!